# Golang Parsing of ProtoBuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm new to Golang and I am trying to write an home automation framework in Golang, using the Micro framework and Protobuf framework.

I am currently having a hard time trying to implement a simple registry type service.

An example of the problem I am having is that I have the following, I want to be able to get a list of devices, provided a client does a GET request to `http://localhost:8080/view/devices`

I have the following protobuf definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";

service DRegistry {
    rpc View(ViewRequest) returns (DeviceRegistry) {}
} 

message DeviceRegistry {
    repeated Device devices = 1;
}

message ViewRequest {
    string Alias = 1;
}

message Device {
    string Alias = 1;
    string HWAddress = 2;
    string WakeUpMethod = 3;
    repeated string BoundServices = 4;
}
```

Then in my service defination I have the following:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    micro "github.com/micro/go-micro"
    proto "github.com/srizzling/gotham/proto/device"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

// DRegistry stands for Device Registry and is how devices register to Gotham.
type DRegistry struct{}

var devices map[string]proto.Device

func (g *DRegistry) View(ctx context.Context, req *proto.ViewRequest, rsp *proto.DeviceRegistry) error {
    filter := req.Alias
devices, err := filterDevices(filter)
rsp.Devices = devices
}

func filterDevices(filter string) (*[]proto.Device, error) {
    // Currently only supports listing a single service for now
    // TODO: expand filter to be more consise
    filteredDevices := make([]proto.Device, 0, len(devices))
    for _, e := range devices {
        for _, f := range e.BoundServices {
            if f == filter {
                filteredDevices = append(filteredDevices, e)
            }
        }
    }
    return &filteredDevices, nil
}

func main() {
    service := micro.NewService(
        micro.Name("DRegistry"),
    )
    proto.RegisterDRegistryHandler(service.Server(), new(DRegistry))

    if err := service.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that my IDE (Visual Studio Code) is complianing that I `cannot use devices (type *[]device.Device) as type []*device.Device in assignment` which is confusing.

TLDR: How do I assign a collection of proto.Devices to the proto.DeviceRegistry?

Comment: Hi! On what line do yo get the error message? 
`*[]device.Device` -- pointer to a slice of `device.Device`.
`[]*device.Device` -- slice of pointers to a `device.Device`.
This read might be useful to you: https://divan.github.io/posts/avoid_gotchas/

Comment: That was a good documentation thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func filterDevices(filter string) ([]*proto.Device, error) {
    // Currently only supports listing a single service for now
    // TODO: expand filter to be more consise
    filteredDevices := make([]*proto.Device, 0, len(devices))
    for _, e := range devices {
        for _, f := range e.BoundServices {
            if f == filter {
                filteredDevices = append(filteredDevices, &e)
            }
        }
    }
    return filteredDevices, nil
}
```

There *is* a difference between a slice of pointers ([]*) and a pointer to a slice (*[]). You are returning a pointer to slice, whereas what you want is a slice of pointers. We can solve this by:

- Updating your `filterDevices` signature to return a slice of pointers
- Updating your `make` call to make a slice of pointers
- Taking the address of `e` in your call to append (we want a slice of pointers to devices)
- *Not* returning the address of the slice